# Xcode build but don't create Executable

Tags: xcode, macos, build

I use a previous Xcode 3 project and built it successfully on the Mac SDK 10.6.

What I don't understand is that not any executable is generated :

- I've look at the scheme and Run is checked,
- the path to the executable I selected the previous executable for the run and then deleted that old executable to be sure that the new will be built.

Strangely, no executable is built.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xcode 4 changes the default build location. It's no longer going into `$(SRCROOT)/build`, but `~/Library/Xcode/DerivedData/...` where `...` is a project-specific folder. Right-click the executable in Xcode and choose "Show in Finder".

Comment: Well ... no DerivedData could be found, the only thing I've got was in "../mySoftwareName/buid/mySoftwareName.build/Release/mySoftwareName.build/Object-normal/i386/ where I found a console icon exe that 'seems' to work but I had to add nib and plist files to run it. Is that normal ?

Comment: AFter many searches, found DerivedData by hand (finder didn't) but no exe ; 2 Errors appears now (????) : the pkg was missing so I copied one from the old build and now stucked with "ld : file not found" how these are linked

Comment: Good answer. However, for Xcode 4, the build directory seems to have changed to: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/your-project/Build/Product/Debug. Not sure why they keep changing it...

Comment: @Hassan: hopefully the "show in Finder" menu item still works :)

Comment: @GrahamLee It does. That's the only way I was able to find it.